# jQuery: Press button to add class AND remove all other classes

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement, click, toggle

so I have the following HTML Code

```
<div class="btn" id="b">Blue</div>
<div class="btn" id="r">Red</div>
<div class="btn" id="g">Green</div>
<div class="colorfield wide"></div>
```

**This is what I try to achieve:**

If I press the blue button, I need the .colorfield to become:

```
<div class="colorfield wide BLUE"></div>
```

If I press any other button, I need .BLUE removed and the other color-class added instead.

I know that this is a rather simple toggle, but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var n = $(".btn").not(this).map(function() {return $(this).text()}).get().join(" ");
  $(".colorfield").removeClass(n).addClass($(this).text());
});
```

This will remove and add the class relative to the button you press.

**Demo**

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var n = $(".btn").not(this).map(function() {return $(this).text()}).get().join(" ");
  $(".colorfield").removeClass(n).addClass($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.colorfield{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}

.colorfield.Blue{
  background-color:Blue;
}
.colorfield.Red{
  background-color:Red;
}
.colorfield.Green{
  background-color:Green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" id="b">Blue</div>
<div class="btn" id="r">Red</div>
<div class="btn" id="g">Green</div>
<div class="colorfield wide"></div>
```

Comment: Genious! Thank you so much!